# LD-JSON causes Web application error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8

I have a website created in .netcore 2.0 and when I add schema.org markup to the website it returns a 404 error for the website.

For example adding the following code at the bottom of the body

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://website.com",
    "name": "wbs",
    "description": "Web Studio"
}
</script>
```

It returns a 404 error. If I remove that ld-json then the website runs as normal.

I'm hosting the website on a windows server machine running IIS 8; is it something with the IIS settings?

Comment: Simply adding something to a view is not going to cause a 404. There's something else going on here.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yeah I know, it shouldn't be a 404. I've looked over the error logs and event error log in windows and nothing. I'm going to move the source code to the server tonight and try to run it from VS17 and see if I can find an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was obvious once I put the code into the IDE, I forgot to escape the `@` in razor.

So the code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://website.com",
    "name": "wbs",
    "description": "Web Studio"
}
</script>
```

would become:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://website.com",
    "name": "wbs",
    "description": "Web Studio"
}
</script>
```